# Difference between ENVIRONMENT PRODUCTION and ENVIRONMENT LIVE in paypal

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

```
// set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION to move real money.
// set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX to use your test credentials
// from https://developer.paypal.com
// set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK to kick the tires without
// communicating to PayPal's servers.
```

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK#testing

I want to know difference between `LIVE` and `PRODUCTION` mode in sdk I did not find documentation for `LIVE` mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find documentation [here](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-Android-SDK/), which says that LIVE is deprecated, and to use PRODUCTION.